# Lotus XML Export of Subforms

Tags: xml, export, lotus-notes, subform

I am creating an XML export for Lotus Notes.
I get it working with all fields on the form itself, but I cannot access the data saved to subforms. How do I access them?

A friend of mine told me that they are stored in the form itself, but this does not seem to be the case.

Do I have to create a seperate view for every subform in order to extract it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to export documents (data) or forms/subforms (design) as XML? Please show your working code you have so far if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you're exporting a form or a document.

If you are exporting a form to find out what-all fields are on that form, you have to scan the DXL for **field** elements, but you must also scan for **subformref** elements, then locate and export those subforms separately to look for **field** elements on them (and also additional **subformref**s). This only works for subforms that are directly included in a form. It is also possible to include a subform on the form via a computed subform form, in which case it is not easy to resolve the subformref to determine which subforms might be included on the form (and therefore, which fields are on the form when it is used).

If you are exporting a document, on the other hand, it will include all the items that were contributed by subforms during editing. However, because of subform formulas and because the design of the form might change, the items in a particular document reflect the state of the design when the document was last edited, and might not match the current form design.

Answer (score 0):

Subforms are just components that can be added to a form.

You need to have a subform embedded within a form to use it.

The fields for both the form and any subforms eventually become items on a document when the document is saved.

So if you want to export the data from a subform, you need to find which forms contain the subform and then create a view of documents that use those forms and export those documents.